# Scriptural reference for the "5 Super-Sacred Banyan Trees"?

Tags: belief, plants, banyan-tree

Although all Banyan trees are considered Sacred. **However, there is a popular belief for [5 Special Types of Banyan Trees](https://hindi.webdunia.com/sanatan-dharma-article/hinduism-ten-sacred-tree-113091300016_3.html) that are considered to be of even a higher "religious-theological" importance,** owing to their various connections with divinities and other related theological events.

These **five "Super-Sacred Banyan Trees"** are:

> **1. The [AkṣhayaVaṭa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akshayavat)** ( अक्षयवट ):
>  Fabled to be in the
> Prayāgrāja.
>   <sup>(probably related to the popular incident of
> Ṛṣi Mārkaṇḍeya watching "baby" Viṣhṇu on a leaf after the
> *Pralaya*).</sup>
>
> ---
>
> **2. The [PanchaVaṭa](https://nashik.gov.in/tourist-place/panchvati/)** ( पंचवट ):
>  Fabled to be in the
> Nashik.
>   <sup>(probably related to the ancient Panchavaṭī (from
> the Rāmāyaṇa))</sup>
>
> ---
>
> **3. The [VanśhīVaṭa](https://bharatdiscovery.org/india/%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%82%E0%A4%B6%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%9F,_%E0%A4%AD%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%82%E0%A4%A1%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%A8)** ( वंशीवट ):
>  Fabled to be in the Mathurā, Braja-Maṇḍala. 
>   <sup>(probably related to Śhrī
> Kṛiṣhṇa's childhood-pastimes in the the Braja region.)</sup>
>
> ---
>
> **4. The [GayāVaṭa or BaudhaVaṭa](https://www.jagran.com/spiritual/sant-saadhak-9587.html)** ( गयावट / बौधवट  ):
>  Fabled to be in the Gayā.
>   <sup>(probably related to the Buddha -
> Viṣhṇu's incarnation or [the incident of four curses by Mātā Sītā](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/44979/the-four-curses-and-a-boon-by-dev%C4%AB-s%C4%ABt%C4%81))</sup>
>
> ---
>
> **5. The [SiddhaVaṭa](https://www.ixigo.com/siddhavat-ujjain-india-ne-1281770)** ( सिद्धवट ):
>  Fabled to be in the Ujjain.
>   <sup>(probably related to the stories of Bhagvatī
> Pārvatī and Bhagvān Śhiva)</sup>

---

**Question:**

Please provide all the related stories from the canonical texts, for each of these five trees, along with their scripturally given location.

Also, where exactly in the texts are these five trees mentioned together, and said to have "Super-Sacred" religious Significance?